# German Umlauts are not shown after being exctracted from a ZIP file

Tags: php, unzip

I've never have problems to work with ZIP files before but recently I've loaded a zip file in the system with some folders in it, where the name of the folder is "bülderß" (with german umlaut and ß) just for test porposes. The problem is that after I extract this zip file, the folder's exctracted as expcetded but its name is not shown correctly (the umlaut and ß are replaced). Originally I thought the problem was with collation, but so far I haven't have success in fixing this problem. Does someone have an idea of why the umlauts are not shown correctly after the folder is exctracted?

kindly,

M.J.

Comment: The problem is probably with the character set. Have you looked at this thread already, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?

Comment: I had thought the same, but I've tried several manners to set this charset, but I haven't succeded so far. Is there an exactly place or way to set the right charset for everything inside a ZIP file??. I've also tried: iconv('cp850', 'utf-8') .... I've tried this with any possible charset, but nothing so far :(